# CSS3: show/hide icon in li a

Tags: html, css

I have this code for show/hide icon using css hover:

HTML:

```
<li>
   <span class="tools"><a href="javascript:void()"><i alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="icon-remove-sign" onclick=deleteBox("1")></i></a></span>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.box .todo-list > li> a> .tools {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  color: #f56954;
}
.box .todo-list > li> a:hover .tools {
  display: inline-block;

}
```

Now This Not Worked and not hide my icon. if i remove `> a>` from code this worked and hide but when add `a>` not worked.
how do can i fix this problem?

Comment: can you add your deleteBox()

Comment: "If i remove `> a>` from code this worked" Then you can fix it by removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS selectors are slightly wrong, try:

```
.box .todo-list > li > .tools > a
```

And

```
.box .todo-list > li > .tools > a:hover
```

The selector parts need to go in the same order as the elements that they select are nested in the HTML.

Check out the [W3C Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: i need to show/hide in li not in a. This Worked For Me: `.box .todo-list > li:hover > .tools > a`

Answer (score 0):

The `>` selector means *immediate descendent*.

In your markup, the *immediate descendant* of the `li` is the `span.tools`.

Therefore, `li > a` does not select anything.

But, `li > .tools > a` *does* select the `a` element.

An excellent write-up can be found here: [Child and Sibling Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

The `>` selector above is a child combinator selector. This means it will only select elements that are direct children of a parent. In otherwords, it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper.

So

```
.box .todo-list > li > .tools > a
```